# ultisnips expand not working and I can't figure out why

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I removed practically everything while troubleshooting.  Vim opens without error, :UltiSnipsEdit works but when I enter snip`<tab>` an actual tab is entered.  My current vimrc.  The configs have been copied from github for both Vundle and UltiSnips.

```
set nocompatible
filetype off

"set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'

filetype plugin indent on

let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"

" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
```

verbose imap `<tab>`

```
i  <Tab>       * <C-R>=UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim
```

:version

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 10 2014 09:33:13)
Included patches: 1-135
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +cindent         +conceal         +digraphs        +farsi           +gettext         +libcall         +mksession       +mouse_netterm   -mzscheme        +profile         +scrollbind      +syntax          +textobjects     +visualextra     +X11
+arabic          +clientserver    +cryptv          +dnd             +file_in_path    -hangul_input    +linebreak       +modify_fname    +mouse_sgr       +netbeans_intg   +python          +signs           +tag_binary      +title           +viminfo         -xfontset
+autocmd         +clipboard       +cscope          -ebcdic          +find_in_path    +iconv           +lispindent      +mouse           -mouse_sysmouse  +path_extra      -python3         +smartindent     +tag_old_static  +toolbar         +vreplace        +xim
+balloon_eval    +cmdline_compl   +cursorbind      +emacs_tags      +float           +insert_expand   +listcmds        +mouseshape      +mouse_urxvt     +perl            +quickfix        -sniff           -tag_any_white   +user_commands   +wildignore      +xsmp_interact
+browse          +cmdline_hist    +cursorshape     +eval            +folding         +jumplist        +localmap        +mouse_dec       +mouse_xterm     +persistent_undo +reltime         +startuptime     -tcl             +vertsplit       +wildmenu        +xterm_clipboard
++builtin_terms  +cmdline_info    +dialog_con_gui  +ex_extra        -footer          +keymap          +lua             +mouse_gpm       +multi_byte      +postscript      +rightleft       +statusline      +terminfo        +virtualedit     +windows         -xterm_save
+byte_offset     +comments        +diff            +extra_search    +fork()          +langmap         +menu            -mouse_jsbterm   +multi_lang      +printer         +ruby            -sun_workshop    +termresponse    +visual          +writebackup     -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libdrm -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/inclu
de/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --
param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -l
pangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -lncurses -lelf -lnsl   -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/li
b/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynami
c   -lruby -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm  -L/usr/lib
```

ls -la .vim folder

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 trevor users 4.0K Mar 26 12:37 ./
drwx------ 29 trevor users 4.0K Mar 26 12:56 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4 trevor users 4.0K Mar 26 12:36 bundle/
drwxr-xr-x  2 trevor users 4.0K Mar 26 12:47 UltiSnips/
```

Thanks in advance for any help!  I have been tearing my hair out trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I figured it out.  So with the current version there is no default snippets not even snip `<tab>`.  Once I added this: `Bundle 'honza/vim-snippets'` Everything started working.

Comment: @benjifisher: I am working on it.  They don't let you answer your own question when you are new... Tomorrow I will be able to accept the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. So with the current version there is no default snippets not even snip `<tab>`. Once I added this: `Bundle 'honza/vim-snippets'` Everything started working.

Comment: Could you expand this? I organized the snippets by language (python.snippets, tex/*.snippets). How do I add a default?

Answer (score 7):

In my case, newly-defined custom snippets were not expanding.

Per the help file, I had defined a directory where my snippets were to be located:

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir="/Users/tony/ultisnips"
```

:UltiSnipsEdit! showed this directory in the list of selectable snippets files to edit. So I thought everything should work. I could add snippets via :UltiSnipsEdit to my custom file just fine. But, apparently, that isn't sufficient to actually get UltiSnips to find files therein when expanding.

My snippets were only expanded after I added the same directory to the list of directories to be searched:

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["/Users/tony/ultisnips", "UltiSnips"]
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case UltiSnips wasn't expanding because I had `set paste` in my .vimrc. Turning on that setting disables key mappings in the insert mode. Try to remove that setting. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, UltiSnips wasn't working on NeoVim, without any error message.

`:UltiSnipsEdit` returned `"Failed to load python3 host"`, which led me to https://github.com/fsharp/vim-fsharp/issues/96.

UltiSnips apparently needs the `neovim` Python package, so running `pip install neovim` solved the problem.